# How to add an image as a summary to Android preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I want to create a regular `PreferenceActivity` which will have the value of the preference as the summary of that preference.

Is there a way to add a picture as the value of a preference (for example, a connectivity preference which will have a green light for a connected status or a red light for disconnected status)? I'm not sure how to do such a thing when the summary is not a simple text.

Comment: instead of use appropriate image based on preference

Answer (score 0):

First solution,you can save image to your sdcard and record its path in preference;

Second solution,you can use [Base64](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/util/Base64.html) to encode your image to string and save it like normal string,when retreive it from preference use Base64 to decode it to Bitmap.Like this:

```
public Bitmap stringtoBitmap(String string){
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    try {
        byte[]bitmapArray;
        bitmapArray=Base64.decode(string, Base64.DEFAULT);
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapArray, 0, bitmapArray.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}


public String bitmaptoString(Bitmap bitmap){
    String string=null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG,100,bStream);
    byte[]bytes=bStream.toByteArray();
    string=Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
    return string;
}
```

Comment: ok but I want to display that image as the summary of the preference. Not displaying only its string.

Comment: @JJAb What does you mean **"the summary of the preference"**

Comment: all preferences got a value right? for example a preference called "number of something" can have the value of "2". I want a preference which it's value is a picture like the example I wrote in my question

Comment: @JJAb yes,I have figured that base64 can encode your picture to string,then you can use it like we use string to save preference normally.

Comment: but I don't need to save a picture for a later use. What I need is to display an image from my resources as the value for a preference so the user will see it visually in the preference activity.

Comment: sorry,I can't get you,I think you'd better explain your problem more clearl in this question.

Comment: I just need to display a picture in the preference. No text at all. Only a picture.